# How to convert predicted values into binary variables and save them to a CSV

Tags: r

I have made a decision tree model on test data then used it to predict vales in a test dataset.

```
dtpredict<-predict(ct1, testdat, type="class")
```

The output looks like:

```
      1       2       3       4       5       6 
    Class_2 Class_2 Class_6 Class_2 Class_8 Class_2
```

I want to write a csv to look like:

```
id, Class_1, Class_2, Class_3, Class_4, Class_5, Class_6, Class_7, Class_8, Class_9
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0
4, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
6, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: How is your data store? Is it a data.frame or data.table? Look at the `write.table` and `write.csv()` base R functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a package called **dummies** that does that well...

```
install.packages("dummies")
library(dummies)

x <- factor(c("Class_2", "Class_2", "Class_6", "Class_2", "Class_8", "Class_2"),
            levels = paste("Class", 1:9, sep="_"))

dummy(x, drop = FALSE)

     xClass_1 xClass_2 xClass_3 xClass_4 xClass_5 xClass_6 xClass_7 xClass_8 xClass_9
[1,]        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
[2,]        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
[3,]        0        0        0        0        0        1        0        0        0
[4,]        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
[5,]        0        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        0
[6,]        0        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
```

All that remains is to get rid of the "x" but this should not be too hard with something like this:

```
d <- dummy(x,drop = FALSE)
colnames(d) <- sub("x", "", colnames(d))
```

and then to save to disk:

```
write.csv(d, "somefile.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks Dominic, that worked. I had to remove x by:                      colnames(d)<- sub("x", "", colnames (d))

Comment: Ah ok, I'll make the edit. Thx for the feedback and glad it worked. Don't forget to accept the answer as it's good for your rep too! :)

Answer (score 0):

Uh, what are the 010101's - logicals? If so they don't make much sense in your example all are class 1 (doesn't correspond to your example dtpredict). If they are logicals....

```
# if dtpredict is a factor vector, where the values are the classes
# and the names are the boolean values:
values = as.numeric(as.character(names(dtpredict)))
classes = as.character(dtpredict)
x = data.frame(id=names(classes))
for(class in sort(unique(classes)){
     x[ , class] = as.numeric(sapply(classes, FUN=function(p) p==class])
}
write.csv(x, 'blah.csv')
```

Comment: Hey Hillary, sorry new to this world ... if you look at my post again it seems like someone corrected it so that the 0 and 1's correspond with the previous output I included... so the 0 and 1's represent whether an object is in that class or not. I tried your code but it did not work. I'd like to see it run because its seems more elegant than having to remove the x afterward like Dominic's work. So answer your question I believe dt predict is a factor vector? but not sure?

Comment: Hey William, no problemo. Okay, so they are logicals - but they are stuck in factor variables. I think I thought the classes were the names and the logicals were the values, but it might be switched. Maybe try this updated code? If the code didn't work, error messages are always handy.